# reading sql query results into variable in js

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is like this:

```
function getNEO(state, callback) {
    var conString = "postgres://alexa:al@alexadb2.cgh333p2.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/alexa";

    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect();
    var data = '';
    var query = client.query("SELECT avg(Math) as math,  avg(Reading) as reading FROM sat_scores WHERE State = '" + state + "'");
    console.log("query is: %s", query);
    query.on('row', function(row) {
            console.log("Row cnt is: %s", row.math);
            console.log("row is: " + row)
            data += row;
        });
    console.log("made it");
    query.on('end', function() {
    callback(data);
        });
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
  getNEO(st, function(results){

    console.log("results: " + results);

    speechOutput = "There are " + results.math + " objects near the earth. ";

    callback(sessionAttributes,
      buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
  });
```

but the results are coming back as `undefined`...how do I properly call the results back into the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You're handling the *results* as a string in the callback where you collect the data by using *+=*.

And then you access to *results*, as it should be an object.

Maybe *results* it's an array of rows objects, so you should concatenate each row by:

```
var data = [];
// ... code cut...
data.push(row);
```

And the *results.math* should be *results[0].math*.

Comment: so I replace `data += row` with `data.push(row);`?

Comment: Yes, but change the *data* initialization as I did in my post first. And try to access to arrays element later.